# React radio buttons

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I'm trying to create a yes-no radio buttons with react but **using only one state**. Thus, I have something like this :

```
<label className="radio-inline">
        <input
             type="radio"
             name={this.props.nameYes}
             defaultChecked={this.props.state}
             onChange={this.props.onChangeEmailNotifications}
             value="yes"/>Yes
</label>
<label className="radio-inline">
         <input
             type="radio"
             name={this.props.nameNo}
             defaultChecked={!this.props.state}
             onChange={this.props.onChangeEmailNotifications}
             value="no"/>No
 </label>
```

The state I pass with a parent component is set to true.

This onChange function is :

```
changeCheckboxState: function(event){
    var chcName = event.target.name;

    switch(chcName){
        case "chcEmailNotificationsYes":
            this.state.user.emailNotifications = event.target.checked;
            this.setState({user: this.state.user});
            console.log('checkbox ' + chcName + " state je : ", this.state.user.emailNotifications);
            break;
        case "chcEmailNotificationsNo":
            this.state.user.emailNotifications = !event.target.checked;
            this.setState({user: this.state.user});
            console.log('checkbox ' + chcName + " state je : ", this.state.user.emailNotifications);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Sad smo u default");
    }
}
```

But those radio buttons aren't working. In console log I see that the state is changed, but it doesn't have effect on the radio buttons.

And is there any way to set the state to null at the beginning, that buttons aren't checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `checked` instead of `defaultChecked` as input radio props

Comment: Yes that did the trick. And how can I solve the problem if I set the state to null. If I set it now to null my NO button is checked.

Comment: do `checked={this.props.state?this.props.state:undefined}` and  `checked={this.props.state?!this.props.state:undefined}`.

Comment: Yes. Great. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your radio buttons are not being checked as React is expecting a click event (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#potential-issues-with-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons), according to that link you'll need to remove the call to preventDefault. Your syntax also appears incorrect to me -

This is a prop not state (If this is correct I'd suggest using a different property name)
`defaultChecked={this.props.state}`

It should look something like this 
`defaultChecked={this.state.xxxx}`

With regards to the setting of state, you can use `getInitialState` to set the state to `null`, this can then be updated `onChange` or using a click method.

Your use of `defaultChecked` appears correct.

Comment: I changed defaultChecked to checked and that did the trick. It is in the state, and syntax and everything works fine. I just didn't want to create a big post.  And how can I solve the problem if I set the state to null. If I set it now to null my NO button is checked.